# Sunspot Solr will not start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

If I try :

```
$ bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:run --trace
```

It returns :

```
** Invoke sunspot:solr:run (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute sunspot:solr:run
java version "1.6.0_37"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_37-b06-434-11M3909)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.12-b01-434, mixed mode)
rake aborted!
No such file or directory - solr/runtime/apache-solr-3.5.0/example
```

I don't remember deleting this.. though I do work on a few projects at the same time.. Does anyone know what I need to do to resolve this?